# Validation rule for Junction Object to check if both parents have been repeated or not

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am creating a junction object called Candidate_Position.This has two parents candidate and position.I have to go to the Candidate Detail page and in the related list create a new Candidate Position.The next page is a VF page where I select the Position to associate with the new Candidate Position and click save.The condition however is,I have to validate if the position I am associating is not already associated with any  Candidate Position having the same Candidate parent.
       For example if there is Candidate "Paul",and under that I am creating a Candidate Position trying to associate Position "Dev",the other Candidate Positions under Candidate "Paul" should not have "Dev" as parent Position.**If the user tries to add the "Dev" then they should get error as "Cannot Add this Position to this Candidate Position"**

*So what Validation Rule I have to give for the Junction Object?
If validation rules are not the way to show this kind of error,then should I use something else? BTW i need to use this junction object anyhow.*

I am completely new to Salesforce,and would appreciate some answers.Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't need a Junction object or you don't need this Validation Rules.
Junction object allows you to create many to many connection between object, which are trying to avoid with this VR.
To avoid VR I suggest you remove Candidate_Position object at all and create a lookup on a Position object to Candidate. This will be one to one, which you are trying to achieve with VR.

EDIT:

ok, If it is a VF page, then in save method you need to `[SELECT Id FROM Candidate_Position WHERE Position = :currentPositionId]`. Check if it is 0. If it is not, then you already have Candidate_Position with currently selected Position.

EDIT #2:

I think, you should be able to use [VLOOKUP](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP) function in VR.

Comment: The thing is,I actually need this junction object for the future scenarios specific to my project.The problem is ,I have to figure out how to show error message "Position has already been used by another Candidate Position of the same Candidate parent object" when I try to add that Position .I thought if we can achieve this through Validation rule.If that is not the case,is there any other way I can achieve this scenario?

Comment: Yes adding this condition for the save method in VF page might work.Thanks a lot. :-)